# JavaScript do something during the settimeout

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

Say I want to do something after 10000ms, but do something else during that 10000ms. How should I use JavaScript to implement this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please at least give us an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place the code immediately after the call to `setTimeout()`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // Code to be executed after timeout goes here
}, 10000);
// Code to be executed immediately goes here
```

Answer (score 2):

After you call the `setTimeout()` the code continues. So it will happen before the `setTimeout()` fires.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` call is asynchronous and you can't say that do this thing in first 1000ms and then do that was given to setTimeout. When callback given to setTimeout will be executing, another code will also be executing.

e.g.

```
// some statements
setTimeout(function(){
    // code that will be executed after 1000ms
}, 1000);

// some more statements that will be executed before above callback
// unless there are too many lines that are taking more than 1000ms,
// Then in that case, above callback execution will not block the 
// global/main scope execution.
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your function runs until it ends, so put anything you want to run before the interval after the settimeout. The timeout will only be called at the end of the function event if it would be set to 0ms.

```
function(){
<code>
settimeout(function(){
<code>
}, 10000)
<code you want to rum>


}
```